# iOS passing information from different viewcontrollers swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller

I've currently got an application where you type one thing into one view and it appears in another view. Should I simply be doing this by sending the information to a database and then retrieving it on the other view or is there a way to directly pass this information?

Comment: @EricAya Thanks for the tip! I'll make sure that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, have a look into Segues

Comment: I'm currently doing everything programmatically. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send information from one ViewController to another are segues.

**You can use it Like this:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        let yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.value = yourValue
```

And in your yourNextViewController class.

```
class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var value:Int! // or whatever
```

You can call this also programmatically:

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifierInStoryboard", sender: self)
```

**Set values from your DestinationViewController back to your Primary (First) ViewController**

**1.** Implement a protocol, for example create a file called protocol.swift.

```
    protocol changeUserValueDelegate {
       func changeUser(toValue:Bool)
    }
```

**2.** set the delegate on your second View

```
    class yourNextViewControllerClass {

    var delegate:changeUserValueDelegate?
```

**3.** set the delegate on load (prepareForSegue)

```
    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
        yourNextViewController.delegate = self
```

**4.** add Function to FirstViewController

```
    func changeUser(toValue:Bool) {
        self.currentUserValue = toValue
    }
```

**5.** call this function from your SecondViewController

```
     delegate?.changeUser(true)
```

**6.** Set the delegate in your FirstViewController

```
    class FirstViewController: UIViewController, ChangeUserValueDelegate {
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Is there a link to a tutorial you can post here?

Comment: This was an answer from me on another question. But there are lots of Tutorials: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Answer (score 0):

if You are doing it programatically then you can give your destination view controller a identifier in the storyboard and when you move to the Viewcontroller get this viewcontroller using this identifier and add a property to the second view controller to get the text you have written

Example :

```
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
            let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewControllerIdentifier") as! UserBasicInfoViewController
            secondViewController.Text = self.textField.text
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfile, animated: true)
```

Or

```
       self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```